# Right way to close the pycharm container

Tags: python, docker, pycharm

I am not a newbie with docker and container. However, I am currently working with images and containers that are not mine. Will immediately killing them all have any side effects on my work?

```sh
$ docker images
REPOSITORY                           TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
<none>                               <none>              53c85f12be2c        19 hours ago        90.9MB
python                               3.7-alpine          a93594ce93e7        3 days ago          90.9MB
pycharm_helpers                      PY-183.5153.39      7ec86b616b84        2 months ago        37.8MB
pycharm_helpers                      PY-183.4886.43      2e7d72b769f4        3 months ago        37.8MB
python                               3.6-alpine          1837080c5e87        3 months ago        74.4MB
practice-pytorch_webapp              latest              154c086a6ec9        3 months ago        9.07GB
rasa-workshop-pydata-berlin_webapp   latest              154c086a6ec9        3 months ago        9.07GB
jd_webapp                            latest              154c086a6ec9        3 months ago        9.07GB
pycharm_helpers                      PY-183.4284.139     0424a06b7543        3 months ago        37.7MB
jupyter/datascience-notebook         latest              8f8d027f666d        4 months ago        6.31GB
busybox                              latest              59788edf1f3e        5 months ago        1.15MB

$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                     COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                   PORTS               NAMES
2dd089cdc1e5        practice-pytorch_webapp   "tini -g -- jupyter …"   8 weeks ago         Exited (0) 8 weeks ago                       practice-pytorch_webapp_1_1c5021c402c1
09ebd4904164        7ec86b616b84              "/bin/sh"                2 months ago        Created                                      pycharm_helpers_PY-183.5153.39
8accff084b9b        2e7d72b769f4              "/bin/sh"                3 months ago        Created                                      pycharm_helpers_PY-183.4886.43
bf2f8f155d70        0424a06b7543              "/bin/sh"                3 months ago        Created                                      pycharm_helpers_PY-183.4284.139
```

1. What are these images?
2. Is it safe to kill and remove them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you need a cleanup job. You can run `docker system prune` and that will get rid of any unused containers/images/volumes etc from your system.

Comment: Thanks for your attempt. `docker system-prune` will clean out the image without and running container. My question is about running container with state `created`.

Comment: There are container that were created from the images - but never ran. Not sure how you ended up with so many though. Usally people don't run `docker create`